# 1 to many relationship involving multiple fields in power bi

Tags: database, powerbi, field, relationship

How do  you define 1 to many relationship between two tables in Power BI, when multiple columns are involved.

I.E.  Column A, B, and C in table 1 tied to Column E, F, and G in table 2, with a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: between two table you can only have one active relationship.... share some data to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, only one relationship.  But the primary key is broken up into three different fields.  Those three fields are in both tables, the 1: table and the n: table.

Comment: Is it an import model or DirectQuery? If DirectQuery be sure to use `COMBINEVALUES` https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-combinevalues-to-optimize-directquery-performance/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column concatenating the fields like:

tied01 = CONCATENATE( CONCATENATE(your_dataset[Column A], your_dataset[Column B]), your_dataset[Column C])

And to

tied02 = CONCATENATE( CONCATENATE(your_dataset[Column E], your_dataset[Column F]), your_dataset[Column G])

Once you have these two new columns, you can merge them to only one column or create a dynamic table making the reference for the new created columns

Comment: that occurred to me, but is this the only way?  does anybody know?  it seems like this is the only way....